# change support for dlnorm in R

Tags: r, lognormal-distribution

I am using `dlnorm()` as a jumping kernel in R for a parameter with range $(0,\infty]$.
However, the issue is that the range of the log-normal distribution includes zero.
How do I exclude zero from the range? Is there another distribution with the support $(0,\infty]$?

Thanks!

Comment: The range of a lognormal doesn't include zero, but also doesn't include infinity, so $0,\infty)$.  It's possible that, on a computer, you might get underflow to zero, but that will happen with any distribution supported on $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @ThomasLumley oh, I see. Thanks!